# Google Cloud - Communication between 2 computing Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i've created new account for google cloud.
i have 2 computing instance, on the same region, same subnet.
this network also connected with vpn to my office.

server 1 is 192.168.1.10 / 255.255.255.0 / gw : 192.168.1.1
server 2 is 192.168.1.11 / 255.255.255.0 / gw : 192.168.1.1
Office is : 192.168.0.0/24

i've created vpn connection and now when i ping from office to servers - there is response.. from servers to office there is response.
but from server to server - no response. from server to gateway - no response.

i have internet and i can also connect to the internet from that servers.
i have rule allow 192.168.1.0/24 any thing (tcp/icmp/udp)

what i miss?

Thanks ahead

Comment: Did you add routes on either end for the remote subnets?

Comment: they both on the same subnet and this whole subnet have the following route : 192.168.1.0/24 |  next hop is Virtual Network.   they have access to servers located on the remote side (vpn) and from the remote to them..  but they dont have local access - from one server to the 2nd.. and no ping response from the gateway (192.168.1.1)

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I would re-check the firewall rules defined in [Google network](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking). I would also check that packets are not being dropped by a firewall inside the servers.

Answer (score 0):

The VPN shouldn't interfere on the internal communication between the instances. Although the communication internally is allowed to the GCP 'internal IP', I effectively know that 192.168.x.x/x is not a range used internally at all on cloud platform. So, or you are performing the test on the wrong IPs or the firewall rule is defined for addresses that are unknown internally.